# Load HTML files from remote server into android

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to create an app with android webview and it uses local html files from assets folder and it works fine but I want to update the html files from server without updating the app. I googled for days and found nothing.
Can anyone tell me how to do it. Cause I have no idea what to do.
Thanks

Comment: You need to change the code "without updating the app"?

Comment: Why are you out of ideas? Just download the files and use them. You have to resolve some problems of course but you will meet them soon. And maybe you can imagine the problems already.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can not update the files in assets. That is the first problem. But easy solvable.

Comment: Can u plz give me an example @greenapps , #neeraj

Comment: An example of what? You have not shown that you understand the problem. Nor have you told how you are gonna solve it. A few steps have to be taken. All simple. You should tell the steps first. After that you could try to code it.